# Yesod-form package: Problem with running programs it via "wai-handler-devel"

Tags: yesod

All,

I made a copy of hello-forms.hs from yesod-form package, just for doing some experiments.
When I run it via the main function, the server is doing well e.g. on port 2500.
HalloWelt.hs is here.

But when I try to run that program in bash console via wai-handler-devel - being in the directory where the HalloWelt.hs ( http://hpaste.org/48381 ) resides...

wai-handler-devel 2600 HalloWelt withHalloWelt

I get...

Attempting to interpret your app...
Compile failed: NotAllowed "module is not loaded: `HalloWelt' (./HalloWelt.hs)"

What could be the reason for that?

Thank you for any hint -

Best regards
Hartmut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a "module HalloWelt where" at the top of your file.

Oh, and I wasn't ignoring the question on web-devel, I just hadn't had a chance to look into it yet.

Comment: Ok, I add the "module HalloWelt where" *after* the language extensions, it works perfectly. Thank you for Your quick help.